# swiftで、アプリが起動していない状態で、ローカル通知を受信した時にアプリのバッジの数を増やしたい。

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

お世話になります。

アプリが起動していない状態で、
ローカル通知を受信した時にアプリのバッジの数を増やしたいのですが、
ローカル通知を受信した時に、何かの処理をさせるには、
どうすれば良いのでしょうか？

アプリがフォアグラインドの時は、

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
{
}
```

で受け取れるようなのですが、アプリが起動していない時に、
バッジの数を増やす方法がわかりません。

ローカル通知ではこのようなことができないのでしょうか？